# Convert textbox string to int and pass to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting error on line below even after I have convert the `sting` to `int` why?

> Input string was not in a correct format parameter

I tried to use `int32.parse` and that not help

on that line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product_TYPE", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_Product_type.Text);
```

of below code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    string cmdstr = "new_product"; 

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = cmdstr;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product_desc", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TB_Product_desc.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product_TYPE", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_Product_type.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TB_company.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@man_year", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_man_year.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_price.Text);
    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    Button1.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: do try parse instead. string inputString = "abc";
        if (Int32.TryParse(inputString, out int numValue))
            Console.WriteLine(inputString);
        else

Comment: What is in TB_Product_type.Text? is it blank ?

Comment: What value you have in  `TB_Product_type.Text`?

Comment: You need to out a breakpoint on, and inspect the values of your textboxes, one of them is unable to be converted to an int. If you are still unable to resolve it, please post the string values for each input you read out while stopped at the breakpoint.

Comment: input must have something which can  not be converted to integer